# Convergence of an infinite sum at $s=\frac12$?

Tags: number-theory

The following infinite, alternating sum:

$$\displaystyle A(s):= \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( {\frac {s+(-1)^n(1+2\,n)}{{n}^{s}}} \right)$$

converges for $\Re(s)>1$.

In the domain $\Re(s) \le 1$ the sum seems to only converge **EDIT: for finite odd upper bounded sums**, when $s=\frac12$ and it then becomes $2.095285523...$, **EDIT: but does diverge for even upper bounded finite sums**. I am now curious to understand why that is and/or whether it can be proven.

Thanks!

Comment: What methods of convergence testing are you using?

Comment: @abiessu. Have not used a specific method. Used Maple to test increasingly finite sums and saw the numeric convergence (only for $s=\frac12$).

Comment: The difference between two successive partial sums goes to infinity hence one wonders that you observed a numerical convergence.

Comment: @Did. You are right! It only converges for finite sums ending at odd n's. I tested (as a habit) with sums up to 9,99,999,... Thos all converge, but the sum diverges for all even numbers. Any idea why that could be the case?

Comment: @Agno any convergent series must have a general term which converges against 0.

Comment: "The following infinite, alternating sum"... This is a series, not an infinite sum, and it is not alternating.

Comment: @Did. Agree and understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $a_n(s)=(s+(-1)^n(1+2\,n))\,n^{-s}$ and $b_n(s)=a_{2n}(s)+a_{2n+1}(s)$, then the convergence you observe and the values you give for $A(s)$ concern the series $$
B(s)=a_1(s)+\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}b_n(s).
$$
Now,
$$
(2n+1)^sb_n(s)=\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)^s(s+1+4n)+s-3-4n.
$$
Expanding the power as
$$
\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)^s=1+\frac{s}{2n}+\frac{s(s-1)}{8n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right),
$$
one gets
$$
(2n+1)^sb_n(s)=4s-2+\frac{s^2}n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right).
$$
Two cases appear:

- If $s\ne1/2$, then $b_n(s)=\Theta(1/n^s)$ hence $B(s)$ converges if and only if $\Re(s)\gt1$.
- If $s=1/2$, then the term $4s-2$ disappears and $b_n(1/2)=\Theta(1/n^{3/2})$, in particular $B(1/2)$ converges.

This yields the convergence/divergence of the series $A(s)$ since the series $A(s)$ converges if and only if the series $B(s)$ converges and $a_n(s)\to0$:

- The series $A(s)$ converges absolutely if and only if $\Re(s)\gt2$.
- The series $A(s)$ converges if and only if $\Re(s)\gt1$ (and, obviously, not if $s=1/2$).

Comment: Many thanks, Did. You Did it! :-)

Comment: In-Did... :-) You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Any convergent series must have a general term which converges against 0. (Easy to prove. consider $\lim_{n\to \infty} S(n)-S(n-1)$.) This is not the case for your series, so it must diverge.

You are right about the convergence if you pair every two consecutive values.
$a(n):=\frac{(-1)^n (2 n+1)+\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{n}}$,

Then
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(2n)+a(2n+1)$ converges to $\frac{\pi  \left(\left(2 \sqrt{2}-1\right) \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+5\right)+\left(1-2 \sqrt{2}\right) \zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 \pi }$

That is what Mathematica said. The calculation was a bit complicated, so I didn't do it myself. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks and I understand the logic. Still keen to understand why for this finite sum with an odd upper bound, the sum does (seem to) converge for $s=\frac12$. Do you get the same? Any thoughts?

Comment: @Agno See edit. I'm sorry I can't help more.